# Tkinter is opening multiple GUI windows upon file selection with multiprocessing, when only one window should exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have primary.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import ttk
import multiprocessing as mp
import other_script

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

def file_select():

    path = askopenfilename()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        queue = mp.Queue()
        queue.put(path)
        import_ds_proc = mp.Process(target=other_script.dummy, args=(queue,))
        import_ds_proc.daemon = True
        import_ds_proc.start()

# GUI
root = Tk()

my_gui = GUI(root)

# Display

frame = Frame(width=206, height=236)
frame.pack()

ttk.Button(frame, text="Select", command=file_select).pack(anchor='nw')

# Listener

root.mainloop()
```

And other_script.py:

```
def dummy(parameter):
    pass
```

When running this, upon selection of a file, a second GUI window appears. Why? This is undesired behavior, I instead want `dummy` to run.

Thanks.

Comment: Use root.withdraw() to eliminate the Tk() window (which you send to GUI).  askopenfilename() opens it's own window, which is the 2nd one that you are seeing  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm  Note that "dummy" will run after the return from askopenfilename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like with `multiprocessing`, you need to place the code to do with `tkinter` and making your window within the entry point to your program (such that it is not ran more than once through another process).

This means moving the `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause to the 'bottom' of your program and placing the code to do with `tkinter` in there instead. The entry point to your `multiprocessing` will still be protected as it is called after an event, which is defined within the start point.

**Edit:**
The entry point is where your program is entered from, normally when you say `if __name__ == "__main__"`.

By moving the `tkinter` code into the entry point, I mean something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    my_gui = GUI(root)
    frame = Frame(width=206, height=236)
    frame.pack()
    ttk.Button(frame, text="Select", command=file_select).pack(anchor='nw')
    root.mainloop()
```

(At the 'bottom' of your program, i.e. after all functions are defined.)

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I'm having trouble unpacking it. I have the following questions:

1. What constitutes the 'bottom' of the program? Is it after root.mainloop()?
2. When you refer to moving the `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause, what are you referring to? That entire code block, or that entire function? It seems at least the queue.put(path) would need to remain where it is.
3. When you refer to placing the code to do with `tkinter` in "there" instead, where and what is "there"? Is it within the definition? I don't see why `tkinter` code would be there.

Comment: (cont'd) 4. When you refer to an event being defined within the start point, what do you mean? 5. Finally, you refer to the code to do with `tkinter` multiple times... what in particular does that mean? And what's the entry point?

Comment: @user1318135 See my edit. For more information on the entry point, take a look at this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Comment: Is this related to how you can't have an import statement in Python without running the entire imported file? I'm assuming that after other_script.py is called the entire primary.py begins again?